# iOS 14, Xcode Version 12.0 beta 3 "Quoted Include In Framework Header

Tags: xcode, ios14, xcode12

I'm trying to migrate to suuport iOS 14 and I come across this "Update to recommended settings" from Xcode Version 12.0 beta 3.

[image]

After I perform the change, it seems a lot of my Firebase related dependencies show errors such as

`Double-quoted include "FBLPromise+All.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead`

[image]

And once I change the affected line to "angle-bracketed", I get red errors instead.

[image]

Here are my questions

1. What exactly is this "Quoted Include In Framework Header"?
2. How can I integrate this change without running into another warnings or errors?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am on the same boat, hoping for someone to come across a solution soon. I am trying to create a widget and I am stuck here..its been days now. And I am on Beta 4

Comment: I also encountered the same problem. I found this issue page and errors were removed in my own case. Please refer to this link: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5987